# Docker-Compose Error - The Grid has no registered Nodes yet

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

please see below my docker-compose.yml and attached screenshot for hub logs. I am not seeing nodes getting attached to hub, any suggestions how to make it work.

Added screenshots for output of docker-compose.yml and containers created in Docker. When I am trying to launch localhost:4444, i am seeing err - The Grid has no registered Nodes yet

````
version: "3"
services:

  hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"


  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome
    container_name: web-automation_chrome
    depends_on:
      - hub
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    ports:
      - "9001:5900"
    links:
      - hub

  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox
    container_name: web-automation_firefox
    depends_on:
      - hub
    
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    ports:
      - "9002:5900"
    links:
      - hub```


[![DockerContainerCreatedSuccessfully][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiMpK.png
````

Comment: I havr debug further and seeing Nodes logs throwing error - Couldn't register this node: Error sending the registration request: Failed to connect to hub/*:4444

Comment: Why not using the official docker-compose files? https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/trunk/docker-compose-v3.yml